# Delete Named Range with Value '#NAME?' or Refers To '=#NAME?'

Tags: excel, vba

Unable to delete Named Range with #NAME?

How do I add to my VBA to delete this?

I have created the below code, it deletes all the named ranges in my workbook except for one, details are:

Name: _xlfn.IFERROR
Value: #NAME?
Refers To: =#NAME?

````
'Delete All Named Ranges
Dim xName As Name
On Error Resume Next
    For Each xName In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        xName.Visible = True
        If InStr(1, xName.RefersTo, "=#NAME?") > 0 Then xName.Delete
        If InStr(1, xName.RefersTo, "#REF!") > 0 Then xName.Delete
        If InStr(xName.Value, "#REF!") > 0 Then xName.Delete
        xName.Delete
    Next xName
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub```
````

Answer (score 1):

The trick is that `xName.RefersTo` will show the original formula instead of the evaluated value, e.g. `=SomeFormulaThatDoesntExist` instead of `#NAME?`

[image]

You can overcome it by using `Evaluate(xName.RefersTo)` which will return `Error 2029` for `#NAME?` error. Furthermore, you can simply add `IsError(Evaluate(xName.RefersTo))` condition to your code, something like:

```
If IsError(Evaluate(xName.RefersTo)) Then xName.Delete
```

Comment: Thank you Justyna, unfortunately, this hasn't worked.  I'm still left with the one named range that is an error.

I've also tried other methods, but other than deleting this manually, it won't delete.

Comment: That's interesting - would you be able to paste the screenshot of this named range or at least share the formula and the error that is being returned? I'll try to have it replicated on my side.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to comment with screenshots on this website yet, but it seems the error name is being generated from an IFERROR formula, typically caused by compatibility issues with older versions of Excel [link](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Issue-An-xlfn-prefix-is-displayed-in-front-of-a-formula-882F1EF7-68FB-4FCD-8D54-9FBB77FD5025).

Comment: I'm using Office16, and the workbook is in Excel Binary format - so I'm not sure if that has anything to do with this - the search for an answer slowly continues ...

Comment: Thanks for the update - it might be that `xlfn` names are hidden, so they cannot be deleted. Can you try to add `xName.Visible = True` before running the deletion procedure?

Comment: Note: I wonder... even if you delete these names, they might automatically re-appear when saving & re-opening the file, due to Excel evaluating formulas like `IFERROR` (i.e. it will discover that this formula is not being supported in the current version). In such case it might be worth considering deleting the "source" formulas (deleting original `IFERROR` formula itself).

Comment: I can manually delete the range, and fortunately, despite it reappearing, it only appears the once, so I'll live with it. Thanks for all your support.